# Generate a Google ReCaptcha V2 secure token with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, encryption, recaptcha

I need to generate a secure token for Google's ReCaptcha V2, because I need one key to work on many domains.

The process is described here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/secure_token

They provide an example on how to do this at https://github.com/google/recaptcha-java/tree/master/appengine.
But the example uses Java, and I don't know how to translate the encryption stuff to ASP.NET.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm in the same boat as you posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31794193/google-recaptcha-v2-encryption-in-vb-net I'll let you know if anyone comes back with anything.  You may find some of the thigns i have tried helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I went to see your post, I saw someone answered there with a working example of how to do this. Going to check that out right away!

Comment: Yes I was able to implement the solution they provided yesterday, Google really needs to step up their documentation.

Comment: Tested the solution provided in the answer in your thread. Working like a charm!
I do not have enough 'points' to add a comment to your post to thank the author of that example, so I can't thank him personally. But phew... he really made my day! Can't thank him enough!